# ggplot barchart "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" on x-axis of reordered counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data, r-factor

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

I want to have a flipped barchart with a color gradient to distinguish the bars. Below are the first  20 rows of my dataset bb_count is my dataset and the code to generate the barplot. The barplot is plotted correctly but the color gradient is not being applied, instead I get the error:

ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

```
bb_count <- bb %>% 
             count(chord, sort = TRUE)

# chord n
# C:maj 1183
# G:maj 1140
# A:maj 1071
# D:maj 1054
# F:maj 859
# E:maj 839
# Bb:maj    718
# B:maj 503
# Ab:maj    375
# Eb:maj    360
# A:min 328
# E:min 298
# Db:maj    293
# D:min 250
# B:min 236
# N 201
# E:min7    186
# C:min 176
# D:7   176
# A:min7    170

# Creating a bar plot from `bb_count`
bb_count %>%
  slice(1:20) %>%
  mutate(share = n/sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(chord = reorder(chord, share)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = chord, y = share, fill = chord)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 0.95) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  xlab("Share of total chords") +
  ylab("Chord")
```

Comment: `dput(bb_count)` is shorter and easier to reproduce than showing the console output. Better still, dput us the output of your pipeline just before the `ggplot()` line, i.e. store the result from everything up to the `mutate(chord..` line. Then you'd see that the output from `reorder(chord, ...)` is categorical not numerical.

Comment: Also your image link [2] is missing, can you fill it in or else delete that line?

Comment: Also your code still isn't reproducible since you didn't supply `chord`. (Use `dput` not console. We need to see if it's categorical).

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Your `x` is discrete, so you need `scale_x_discrete`

```
df %>%
  slice(1:20) %>%
  mutate(share = n/sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(chord = reorder(chord, share)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = chord, y = share, fill = chord)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 0.95) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete() +
  xlab("Share of total chords") +
  ylab("Chord")
```

[image]

data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("
# chord n
# C:maj 1183
            # G:maj 1140
            # A:maj 1071
            # D:maj 1054
            # F:maj 859
            # E:maj 839
            # Bb:maj    718
            # B:maj 503
            # Ab:maj    375
            # Eb:maj    360
            # A:min 328
            # E:min 298
            # Db:maj    293
            # D:min 250
            # B:min 236
            # N 201
            # E:min7    186
            # C:min 176
            # D:7   176
            # A:min7    170
")
```